# I am looking for some basic mechanical parts to build structures(prototypes)?

Tags: mobile-robot

I am looking for something like this part in these photos:

[image: WHIM Wheelchair - A DIY Electric Powered WHeelchair]
[image]

to make my robot ideas as prototype. But I don't know it's name! Also if there are better options I will happy to know.

Answer (score 1):

Perforated square tubing or "bolt together" framing.

You might also consider 80/20-style T-slot framing.

I'm not associated with McMaster-Carr, but I'm a big fan of theirs. You can find [perforated square tubing on their site here](https://www.mcmaster.com/#perforated-tubing;square-tubing/) and you can find [80/20-compatible T-slot framing here.](https://www.mcmaster.com/#80/20-compatible-t-slotted-framing/)

Of course, if you're looking for 80/20 framing, you could always go to the [80/20 website.](https://8020.net/)

Comment: I always think of these t-slot systems as 'item bar' as my first exposure to this technology was through the the *item MB Building Kit System*. [item Industrietechnik GmbH](http://timeline.item24.com/index.php/en) also happen to be the company who created the first standardised integrated system like this.